# OpenJPA cascade persist on OneToOne relationship

Tags: jpa, websphere, cascade, openjpa, persist

I'm trying to persist to an IBM DB2 database using Websphere which in turn uses an OpenJPA implementation. My issue is that i'm always getting an integrity constraing exception SQLCODE=-530, meaning it can't find the foreign key.

The relationship is as follows

```
@Entity
public class A{
   @Id
   private String id;

   @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL) 
   @JoinColumn(name = "B_ID") 
   private B b; 
}

@Entity
public class B{
   @Id
   private String id;
}
```

Now i try to persist the two entities.

```
final A a = new A(); 
final B b = new B(); 
a.setB(b); 

em.persist(a);
```

The DB owner of the relationship is the table bound to A containing a reference to B while B has no reference to A.

Now when persisting OpenJPA tries to persist the owner of the @JoinColumn first which results in class B not being there and thus isn't able to persist.

Does anybody have a sollution to this issue maitaining the current relationships.
I've already found this post: http://openjpa.208410.n2.nabble.com/Constraint-violation-using-OneToOne-relationship-td6978223.html
but the sollution proposed there doesn't seem to work.